# Mongoose 'find' is returning an empty array when queried with conditional params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of some tweets and I need to fetch the tweets specific to a particular user. I'm using mongoose 'Find' query to find the tweets. I'm taking the user_id from req.params and using it as conditional parameter but mongodb is returning an empty array.

I have tried debugging with console.log and user_id seems to be correct. Type of 'user_id' is String which is expected and i don't seem to find the reason as why an empty array is returned even though there are matching entries in my collection.

Moreover, when i use other conditional parameters(apart from user), entries are fetched with no problem.

```
app.get('/search/:id',(req,res) => {
  var _id = req.params.id;
  if(!users.includes(_id)){
    res.status(400)
    res.send('Sorry... User not present in the list')
  }
  else{
    Tweet.find({user: _id}).then((tweets)=>{
      res.status(200).send(tweets)
    }).catch((e) =>{
      res.status(500).send();
    })
  }
})
```

My mongoose Schema:

`const Tweet = mongoose.model('Tweet',{
  user:{
    type: String,
    trim:true
  },
  text:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim:true
  },
  verified:{
    type: Boolean
  }
})`

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you provide an example id value and Tweet document you expect to find? The document is in the `tweets` collection, right?

Comment: Yes. I have a collection 'tweets'.

Sample document:

`{"_id":"5d0129be839e1711ca1b6d04",
"user":"\"jimmyfallon\"",
"text":"\"Might have to do both!!!\"",
"verified":true}`


I'm passing id as 'user' so that all tweets corresponding to the user are returned.

Comment: Looks like your problem is that you've got embedded `"` chars in the strings you're matching against. It should look like `"user": "jimmyfallon"` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be the problem. I have added " " to the search query and it's working fine. Thanks. 

One thing that is still bothering me is the behavior of mongodb. My "user" parameter is of type String and mongodb is adding "" to the content of my input. Is it a normal mongodb/mongoose behavior ?

Comment: Mongodb won’t add those “” , they must be coming from somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

"I have tried debugging with console.log and user_id seems to be correct. Type of 'user_id' is String which is expected and i don't seem to find the reason as why an empty array is returned even though there are matching entries in my collection. "
accoutring to your this statement you search for  "user_id" is document but you can not define user_id in your mongoose schema

```
const Tweet = mongoose.model('Tweet',{
  user:{
    type: String,
    trim:true
  },
  text:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim:true
  },
  verified:{
    type: Boolean
  }
})
```

use user instead of id

```
app.get('/search/:user',(req,res) => {
  var user = req.params.user;
  if(!users.includes(user)){
    res.status(400)
    res.send('Sorry... User not present in the list')
  }
  else{
    Tweet.find({user: user}).then((tweets)=>{
      res.status(200).send(tweets)
    }).catch((e) =>{
      res.status(500).send();
    })

  }
})
```

Comment: findById() will return only 1 document just like findOne(). I need all the documents having user: req.params.id.

Comment: i think you need one document, so i suggests findById() method if you need all document use then use find() method

Comment: another question are you define user_id in your schema mongo automaticaly insert unique  _id when you insert data to your document.

Comment: As i mentioned, I need to fetch the tweets specific to a particular user. My query here is that the conditional parameter ({user: _id}) doesn't seem to be working here and returning an empty array. Ideally, it should return an array of all documents where user: _id.